# Colocar paginação em tabela

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Meu entendimento sobre javascript muito pouco queria ajuda para adicionar  paginação em tabela html css materialize

```
    <table class="striped" id="id_tabela">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Nome do Cliente</th>                    
              <th>Email</th>                    
              <th>Telefone</th>
              <th>Editar</th>
              <th>Excluir</th>                        
           </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php include_once 'criar/read.php'; ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <ul class="pagination" id="id_tabela">
        <li class="disabled"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#!">1</a></li>
        <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!">2</a></li>
        <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!">3</a></li>
        <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!">4</a></li>
        <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!">5</a></li>
        <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pinzon1992/materialize_table_pagination/master/js/pagination.js">

<script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#id_tabela').pageMe({
              pagerSelector:'#myPager',
              activeColor: 'green',
              prevText:'Anterior',
              nextText:'Siguiente',
              showPrevNext:true,
              hidePageNumbers:false,
              perPage:10
            });

              // Write on keyup event of keyword input element
                    /*$("#search").keyup(function(){

                        _this = this;
                        // Show only matching TR, hide rest of them
                        $.each($("#tabla tbody tr"), function() {
                                alert("Encontrado");
                                if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1)
                                     $(this).hide();
                                else
                                     $(this).show();
                        });
                    }); */
          });
</script>
```

Comment: Poderia adicionar também o seu código JavaScript e descrever qual foi a dificuldade encontrada?

Comment: Ser pode me ajuda eu eu agradeço

Comment: Mas no que precisa de ajuda? Coloque o que fez na pergunta e descreva a sua dificuldade. Se não colocar nada, parecerá que quer que façamos para você.

Comment: obrigado por atenção acho vou resolver so erro na class acho que resolvo